# Major Issue with Testng Custom reporting using IReporter

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to generate my own emailable report in testng. I am implementing IReporter in a base class and then extending base class to write required methods.
But for random runs I am getting my reporter called and for others the output looks like old basic report without my changes.

```
package org.testng.reporters;

public class EmailableReporter
    implements org.testng.IReporter
{
```

And writing my code in:

```
public class EmailableResultReporter extends EmailableReporter {
```

And this behavior is completely random. In 10 runs near about 3-4 runs I am getting my generated report.

Comment: testng version used is 6.8

Comment: how  are you triggerring?  How is the reporter being added to the run?

Comment: I tried two ways, one via program: testng.addListener(...) and also by placing it in testng suite xml.

Comment: So I figured out something, when I am passing <parameter> inside suite, as soon as I removed it, that random report behavior stopped. I am not sure if that is really the case.